# Tool to make homepage using MarkDown files of a GitHub repo

Tags: web, markdown, github

I have several repos at github which are about software, but mostly containm mark-down text.

The pages get rendered to nice HTML at github, but the look/layout is not very nice.

Is there a tool to make a simple homepage from mark-down files in a github repo.

I would like to avoid to run a own webserver.

Here are some examples of the pages:

- https://github.com/guettli/programming-guidelines
- https://github.com/guettli/deadends-of-it
- https://github.com/guettli/lets-fix-js

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you are looking for? Is it static site generators like `Jekyll`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [forestry.io](https://forestry.io/) with gatsby and Hugo (static site generators).

You can import your git repo

[image]

Any changes you make into your .md files via forestry's wysiwyg editor are automatically committed to the origin and if you have integrated CI/CD, they are automatically deployed.

To make your page look fancy, I suggest you look into GitHub pages: https://pages.github.com

Depending on your preference, you could also try a few alternatives like:

https://getpublii.com/

https://www.netlifycms.org/

If you decide to go with forestry, you can fork gitlab's starter pages: https://about.gitlab.com/product/pages/